# ASP.NET website requires login after each compile

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I am working on two ASP.NET websites. Both use custom authentication process based on forms authentication with:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

set in Web.config.

When I compile the first website, it always remembers my credentials I've entered before, like expected.

When I compile the second website, each time it forgets completely all credentials I've entered a minute before, and .ASPXAUTH cookie is not here nevermore.

What can cause the second website to do so? Where to start to search for the resolution of this problem?

Comment: How are you accessing the sites? Are they on a web server, your development workstation, etc? Are you using VS and F5 to run the sites? More information is needed I believe.

Comment: Both websites are currently in debug mode (VS and F5), so on development workstation.

Comment: What is F5?  A web server?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: F5 - a keyboard button which, in Visual Studio, launches the application in debug mode.

Comment: @MainMa Doh! Completely misunderstood F5 there!  I use F5 all the time but thought it was some kind of software tool! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps when the 2nd site recompiles some class or other object changes that is stored in the session so the application has to restart the session, but in the first site the only thing being stored in the session are standard .net objects that havn't been recompiled.  Is this causing a real world problem, it is fairly usual to lose your session state when you recompile a website, but this does not cause any problems i the wild unless you are updating your live code several times a day and kicking users of the system.

Comment: I will see if this is a case to confirm that. I don't remember storing any my-own-class objects in the session, but I am not sure.

The only problem it causes is that for the moment, I have to enter my password each time I want to test the website, which is very annoying. Another way would be to hard-code username/password during debug or to login according to Active Directory accounts, but I just wanted to know why the problem occurs.

Comment: You could use the #if compiler directive to have a section of code that auto logs you in if you are debugging.  The section of code will not be compiled in the release code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Could having a strong name for the assembly be the cause? I'm trying to work out why I'm getting the same problem.